# getSourceData(), afterchange Handsontable js vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, handsontable, ref

I need  getSourceData() afterchange but for it, I need too instance handsontable. i don't know to get instance handsontable on vue. Realty I need all row its has edited

ex.

```
const my_instance = this.$refs.myTable.hotInstance;

console.log(my_instance.getSourceData())
```

My error

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'myTable' of undefined"
found in
--->

vue.js:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'myTable' of undefined
```

MY EXAMPLE https://jsfiddle.net/hmwus0xz/

code:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="hot-preview">
      <HotTable :settings="settings" ref="myTable"></HotTable>
    </div>
  </div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  msg: 'test',
    settings: {
        data: [
          ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
          ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
          ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
          ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
        ],
        colHeaders: true
      },
      afterChange: function (itemodificado, accionHanson) {
            const my_instance  = this.$refs.myTable.hotInstance;

                        console.log(my_instance.getSourceData())
            //mytable 

                if ( accionHanson != 'loadData') {
                    itemodificado.forEach(element => {
                        var fila = my_instance.getSourceData()[element[0]]
                         // fila = my_instance null
                        console.log(fila)
                    });
                }
            },
  },
  components: {
     'hottable': Handsontable.vue.HotTable
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make `data` as a function and `afterChange` as an arrow function in order to get `this` value as a Vue instance.

On loading table `hotInstance` will be null(only once). Check it to avoid errors.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'test',
      settings: {
        data: [
            ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
            ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ],
          colHeaders: true,
          afterChange: (itemodificado, accionHanson)=> {
            if(!this.$refs.myTable.hotInstance) return;
            const my_instance  = this.$refs.myTable.hotInstance;
            console.log(my_instance.getSourceData())
            //mytable 

                if ( accionHanson != 'loadData') {
                    itemodificado.forEach(element => {
                        var fila = my_instance.getSourceData()[element[0]]
                         // fila = my_instance null
                        console.log(fila)
                    });
                }
            },
          },
      }
  },    
  components: {
     'hottable': Handsontable.vue.HotTable
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/ev509wu6/

Comment: fijate que me da esto con vue ´{__ob__: Observer}´  pero   cuando lo hago con js puro me tira lo que deseo '{idalumno: "1648", matricula: "2-2018", nombre_alumno: "Beteta López Rudy Josué ", punteos: {…}}' ya que lo boy a mandar por ajax

Comment: me dice que debo invok ` idalumno: (...)matricula: (...)nombre_alumno: (...)punteos: (...)__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}get idalumno: ƒ reactiveGetter()set idalumno: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get matricula: ƒ reactiveGetter()set matricula: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get nombre_alumno: ƒ reactiveGetter()set nombre_alumno: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)get punteos: ƒ reactiveGetter()set punteos: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)__proto__: Object `

Comment: If you get just `{ob: Observer}`. it seems to the ajax is not finished yet. Try to await the response o reload the component after the data is recivied

Comment: try to update the question with the code you are using on your project. with the responses.

Comment: Hi!! @HANS FELIX RAMOS, you can help me whit this. pleasss -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853736/how-to-load-data-to-handsontable-using-vue-when-amount-or-created

Comment: Let me check the answer!