# Sum from row value, "2 colums" the max handsontable

Tags: javascript, sum, rhandsontable

I have a handsontable where I need to sum cols, the end col has total from all cols summed
I can sum all cols, the problem is cols is dynamics sometimes one-col has a child, in this case,  I need to sum the max of both, but I don't know how can I do it, !when is just one just sum one. if has a child sum just the max both cols.!

ex: **work1** is the parent. the child is **help 1**, the arrays cols came from database

example http://jsfiddle.net/duxL728h/

[image]
[image]

```js
function hexRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
}

var hot = new Handsontable($("#exampleGrid")[0], {
  data: [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  fillHandle: false,
  minSpareCols: 0,
  minSpareRows: 0,
  columns: [{
      data: 'work.name',
      title: 'Name',
      readOnly: true,
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 100
    }, {
      data: 'work.1',
      perent: "1",
      title: 'work 1',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.2',
      perent: "1|h",
      title: 'help 1',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.3',
      perent: "3",
      title: 'work 2',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.4',
      perent: "3|h",
      title: 'help 2',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.5',
      perent: "5",
      title: 'work 3',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.6',
      perent: "6",
      title: 'work 4',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.7',
      perent: "6|h",
      title: 'help 4',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'total',
      title: 'Total',
      readOnly: true,
      width: 100,
      type: {
        renderer: function(instance, td, row) {
          let cols = instance.countCols() - 1;
          let total = 0;

          for (let index = 1; index < cols; index++) {
            total += instance.getDataAtCell(row, index);
          }

          td.innerHTML = total;
        }
      }
    }


  ],
  afterChange: function(changes, source) {

    console.log("proces to save data")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/demo/css/samples.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css">

<div id="exampleGrid" class="dataTable"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean `cols is dynamics sometimes one-col has a child`? can you provide some example for that?

Comment: ex: work1 is the parent. the child is help 1, the arrays cols came from database

Comment: you mean ex: work1 is 5, work2 is 6 and help2 is 7 then the result should be 5+7 = 12, right? Also if you want a quick answers, please mention as many scenario/examples as possible in the question.

Comment: ready! i fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by changing data keys, to easily recognize which col is parent and which col is it's child like below.

```js
function hexRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
}

var hot = new Handsontable($("#exampleGrid")[0], {
  data: [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  fillHandle: false,
  minSpareCols: 0,
  minSpareRows: 0,
  columns: [{
      data: 'work.name',
      title: 'Name',
      readOnly: true,
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 100
    }, {
      data: 'work.1',
      perent: "1",
      title: 'work 1',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'help.1',
      perent: "1|h",
      title: 'help 1',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.2',
      perent: "3",
      title: 'work 2',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'help.2',
      perent: "3|h",
      title: 'help 2',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.3',
      perent: "5",
      title: 'work 3',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'work.4',
      perent: "6",
      title: 'work 4',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'help.4',
      perent: "6|h",
      title: 'help 4',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 50
    }, {
      data: 'total',
      title: 'Total',
      readOnly: true,
      width: 100,
      type: {
        renderer: function(instance, td, row) {
          const cols = instance.getCellMetaAtRow(row);
          cols.shift();
          const values = cols.reduce((acc, ele) => {
            const [type, ind] = ele.prop.split('.');
            const value = instance.getDataAtCell(row, ele.col);
            if (value && (!acc[ind] || value > acc[ind])) {
              acc[ind] = value;
            }
            return acc;
          }, {});


          td.innerHTML = Object.values(values).reduce((acc, e1) => acc + e1, 0);
        }
      }
    }


  ],
  afterChange: function(changes, source) {

    // console.log("proces to save data")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/demo/css/samples.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css">

<div id="exampleGrid" class="dataTable"></div>
```

Comment: thanks!! how to set col Total type: 'numeric', cause has error most be string say!

Comment: @Carlos, not pretty sure about that, After assigning to innerHTML, it'll be string only. What exact issue you are facing?

Comment: when clic in col Total ::::: handsontable.js?91ff:15473 Uncaught Error: Cell type must be a string 
    at getMethodFromProperties (handsontable.js?91ff:15473)
    at getMethodFromProperties (handsontable.js?91ff:15485)
    at Core.cellMethodLookup (handsontable.js?91ff:15486)
    at EditorManager.prepareEditor (handsontable.js?91ff:40042)